# Can someone proofread my javaScript syntax when using indexOf, split and then pasting the splits across various inputs utilizing loops?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, split

I am a self-taught, part-time, by hobby coder.

I am trying to build a javaScript/jQuery tool which will allow for a user to copy rows or columns in Excel, and then paste them in within an online html form, consisting of a grid of `<textarea>`s. The method is to recognize the delimiters in the copied data.

I have been surfing & testing for a while now, and I feel as though I am a hairs breadth away from accomplishing this, but I still can't get it to work.

The example form I am testing with is as below:

[image: sample form for testing image]

The sample data set might be this:

[image: sample data set to be pasted into the form]

I don't want to be too long winded, but I thought it best to share (nearly) the entire code that I have so far, so as to leave out any mysteries:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.inputArea').keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which == 13)
        {
            alert ( "Hello.\n \n Please use your mouse or the [TAB] key to advance to other cells.\n \n The [RETURN] key is disabled to prevent premature submissions of the form.\n \n");
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('.inputArea').focus(function() {
        $(this).addClass("InFocus");
   });
    $('.inputArea').blur(function() {
        $(this).removeClass("InFocus");
   });   
    $('.inputArea').keyup(function() {
        var x = $(this).val();
            if (x.indexOf('\t') > 0 && x.indexOf('\n') > 0) {
            alert ("Hello. \n\n At this time, this form does not support \'copy \& paste\' from both columns and rows from a Excel sheet in the same block.\n\nColumns and/or rows must be copied independantly.\n\n");
            $(this).val("");
            return false;
            }
            else
            if (x.indexOf('\t') > 0) {
                var delT = x.split('\t');
                var dit = $(this).attr('data-id');
                for (var i = 0; i < delT.length ; i++)
                $("#dataInput_" + dit[i]).val(delT[i]);

             }
             else
             if (x.indexOf('\n') > 0) {
                 var delN = x.split('\n');
                 var din = $(this).attr('data-id');
                 for (var i = 0; i < delN.length ; i++) 
                 $("#dataInput_" + din[i]).val(delN[i]);
                 din += 4;

             }
                     return false;
   });
})
</script>



    <style>
        <!--I will skip the styling code-->
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="simpleForm02">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Color</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea data-id="1" class="inputArea colorInput" id="dataInput_1" name="colorInput_row_1" onKeyUp="" ></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea data-id="2" class="inputArea modelInput" id="dataInput_2" name="modelInput_row_1" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea data-id="3" class="inputArea qtyInput" id="dataInput_3" name="qtyInput_row_1" onKeyUp=""></textarea></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea data-id="4" class="inputArea costInput" id="dataInput_4" name="costInput_row_1" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea data-id="5" class="inputArea colorInput" id="dataInput_5" name="colorInput_row_2" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea data-id="6" class="inputArea modelInput" id="dataInput_6" name="modelInput_row_2" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea data-id="7" class="inputArea qtyInput" id="dataInput_7" name="qtyInput_row_2" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea data-id="8" class="inputArea costInput" id="dataInput_8" name="costInput_row_2" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea data-id="9" class="inputArea colorInput" id="dataInput_9" name="colorInput_row_3" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea data-id="10" class="inputArea modelInput" id="dataInput_10" name="modelInput_row_3" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea data-id="11" class="inputArea qtyInput" id="dataInput_11" name="qtyInput_row_3" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea data-id="12" class="inputArea costInput" id="dataInput_12" name="costInput_row_3" onKeyUp=""></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The results I get are that if I copy the top row of sample set data from above, the input gets split, but only the first split gets pasted in the focused `<textarea>`, and the rest disappears.

The only way I can get the split to paste correctly is:

If I reduce the 'data id' by one across the board so that the first 'data id' is 0, instead of 1. And if I replace:

`$("#dataInput_" + din[i]).val(delN[i]);` / `$("#dataInput_" + dit[i]).val(delT[i]);`

with

`$("#dataInput_" + i).val(delN[i]);` / `$("#dataInput_" + i).val(delT[i]);`

Then the tool works, BUT ONLY in 'data id' 0. i.e. the top left `<textarea>` only.

I know there must be some syntax solution in getting the 'data id' loop to work correctly.

Comment: For code reviews head over here - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - stack overflow is intended for specific programming questions.

Comment: @ColinE this sounds like a "find my bug" type of question instead. The code posted to [codereview.se] should work.

Comment: Do you realize `for` without braces only affects the next statement? `din+=4` looks like it's meant to be inside the loop above it - could this be the problem? You should always use braces.

Comment: Thanks @ColinE.  I will look into the cade review site in the future.  thanks

Comment: Thanks also to @Jan Dvorak!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tha main problem was your use of `dit[i]` and `din[i]`. `dit` and `din` are not arrays; this was treating them as character strings, and returning the i'th character, not adding `i` to the value as intended. There was also the loop syntax problem that Jan Dvorak pointed out (you should use an editor that indents the code so you'll see the structure).

```
        if (x.indexOf('\t') > 0) {
            var delT = x.split('\t');
            var dit = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'), 10);
            for (var i = 0; i < delT.length ; i++) {
                $("#dataInput_" + (dit + i)).val(delT[i]);
            }

         }
         else
         if (x.indexOf('\n') > 0) {
             var delN = x.split('\n');
             var din = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'), 10);
             for (var i = 0; i < delN.length ; i++) {
                 $("#dataInput_" + (din + i)).val(delN[i]);
                 din += 4;
             }
         }
```

Comment: Please add a summary of your changes. Just dumping the fixed code here is not going to be useful.

Comment: @JanDvorak I did, you just didn't wait long enough.

Comment: Wow. Didn't even notice the array index bug.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Barmar!  I thank you for introducing me to the parseInt() functionality. And I thank you for the tip on the CodeReview area of StackOverflow.  The fix works like a charm!  Again, many thanks!